Very basic questions about choosing weights for WLS
Hi all – very new to stats and ML here (though with plenty of math experience – I’m not a student looking for homework help, I’m 58, know plenty of math, and am looking to expand my skills).  I performed a simple linear regression (OLS) on some of the continuously-valued columns of the Ames housing data set. (I know I need to learn how to incorporate categorical data at some point). I checked the resulting model for heteroscedasticity, and there are definitely patterns in the residuals, esp. that they get much higher as the fitted values go up.
 
So I am trying a WLS model instead but I’m stuck on assigning the weights. One good resource I have shows examples, but only for a single predictor, whereas I’m using about 10 predictors. That example takes the reciprocal of the fitted data and uses it as a weight, but only for the single predictor. Surely I can’t use that value as the weight for all predictors, right? I imagine that a WLS model where the weights are the all the same is just like an OLS model, though I could be well off base.
 
Any good guidelines or previous answers anyone can point me to?

This is not an answer to your question but in machine learning, the data is almost always standardized (subtract the mean from each sample and divide by the std) before applying any ML algorithm. This generally solves issues with unequal variances for practical purposes!

Yes, I did do z-score normalization on the data (which I think is what you're referring to?). Seems like the problem is still there -- but this is good to know!


I checked the resulting model for heteroscedasticity, and there are definitely patterns in the residuals, esp. that they get much higher as the fitted values go up.

So somehow make a joint model for the mean and the variance, then use the inverse variance as weights.

So I am trying a WLS model instead but I’m stuck on assigning the weights. One good resource I have shows examples, but only for a single predictor, whereas I’m using about 10 predictors. That example takes the reciprocal of the fitted data and uses it as a weight, but only for the single predictor. Surely I can’t use that value as the weight for all predictors, right?

This indicates some misunderstandings! The weight is by observation, that is the line of the data file with $Y_i$, the response and all the corresponding predictors $x_i$. The theoretically optimal weight is the reciprocal of the variance of the error term, but you do not know that, so must somehow estimate it. It is probably best to make a joint model for mean and variance, that can be done with the R package gamlss. Some example at

Are there better approaches than the weighted mean?
and the links therein.


Thank you Kjetil! Yes, as a newbie, I keep forgetting that the weights are per observation, not per predictor. I think you've put me on the right path.
